# Determining the Average Number of $0$s Between $1$s in a String of Arbitrary Length

Tags: combinatorics

Consider a binary string such as $S = 01000100100101101$.  This string has 17 total characters,$|S_0| = 10$ of which are $0$s and $|S_1| = 7$ of which are $1$s.  Comparing the two sets we see there are on average $1.3$ $0$s between each consecutive pair of $1$s.

We can repeat this reasoning for any pair of elements in a string composed from a larger alphabet such as $T^k$ where $T \in [0,1,2,3,...,n-1]$ and $k \in K$ for some index set K.  That is, we can determine the average number of one character type between some other character type.

I have a few questions:

1) How would this be done when looking to compare the frequency with which an element occurs not just pairwise (against one other element), but against some finite set of other elements?

2) Is there a way to do this (or does it even make sense) for infinitely many other elements?

3) Finally, what would happen if the alphabet for $T$ or the index set $K$ describing the string's length was infinitely large?

If this question is too broad and links would concisely answer the question I welcome them.

Comment: The "average number of 0s between each consecutive pair of 1s" is more simply and commonly expressed as "the average run length (of zeroes)"

Comment: @leonbloy Thanks, I will definitely keep that in mind.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should try and be more specific with what you are looking for. One thing you could try and do is given $m$ $1$'s and $n$ 0's at random try and compute the expected average number of 0's between each pair of $1$'s.

Comment: Are you referring to how to handle a string of infinite length with a two letter alphabet?  If so, wouldn't we have to do infinitely many samples for this to provide a good estimate?